# etree.findall: 'OR'-lookup?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I want to find all stylesheet definitions in a XHTML file with `lxml.etree.findall`. This could be as simple as

```
elems = tree.findall('link[@rel="stylesheet"]') + tree.findall('style')
```

But the problem with CSS style definitions is that the order matters, e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/first.css" />
<style>body:{font-size: 10px;}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/second.css" />
```

if the contents of the `style` tag is applied after the rules in the two `link` tags, the result may be completely different from the one where the rules are applied in order of definition.

So, how would I do a lookup that inlcudes both `link[@rel="stylesheet"]` and `style`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible using XPATH:

```
data = """<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/first.css" />
<style>body:{font-size: 10px;}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/second.css" />
"""

from lxml import etree

h = etree.HTML(data)

h.xpath('//link[@rel="stylesheet"]|//style')

[<Element link at 97a007c>,
 <Element style at 97a002c>,
 <Element link at 97a0054>]
```

Comment: funny, I tried that expression with `tree.findall`, it didn't occur to me that `tree.xpath` could work. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! As I was writing I realised that your `findall` expression contained a predicate, which I wasn't aware it would accept. I've not been back to `findall` since becoming familiar with `xpath`.